# WordPress - счетчик постов на странице архивов

Tags: php, wordpress

Имеем стандартный цикл WP:

```html
<?php if ( have_posts() ) :  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <!-- Тут идут посты -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

С постраничной навигацией, нужно вывести счетчик постов. Поможет кто?

**UPD:**
Доработал код:

```html
<?php $counter = 0; ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) :  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <!-- Тут идут посты -->
   <?php $counter++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $counter; ?>
```

Однако, всегда выдает максимальное количество постов на странице, т.е. 10. Как можно обойти это ограничение?

Comment: покажите, как формируется запрос WP_Query

Comment: Собственно так и формируется. Это страница архивов.

Answer (score 2):

Я не совсем понял о каком счетчике постов идет речь. Если нужно вывести количество опубликованных постов, то используй wp_count_posts():

```
<?php
if (have_posts()):
echo wp_count_posts()->publish; // Количество постов
    while (have_posts()): the_post();
    // Цикл
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Такой счетчик обладает существенным недостатком: он выводит общее количество постов. К примеру wp_count_posts('кастомный_тип_поста')->publish; выведет общее количество постов указанного типа. У меня динамические архивы, с фильтрами. Однако, цикл стандартный. Счетчик считает верно, но упирается в максимальное количество постов на странице - 10. Как включить в подсчет пагинацию?

Comment: Вот именно поэтому я и спросил про WP_Query. Вот ровно по этому.

Comment: Хм, может вопрос нубский: но где я его могу посмотреть, на страницах архивов стандартный код if (have_posts()):....

Comment: Можно через get_posts() получить массив кастомного типа постов и сделать count()

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте так:

```
global $wp_query;
$counter = $wp_query->found_posts;
<?php if ( have_posts() ) :  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <!-- Тут идут посты  -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $counter; ?>
```

Должно сработать в общем случае.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение, вдруг кому будет нужно.

```html
<?php echo $wp_query->found_posts; ?>
```

Comment: Это вы в моем ответе это решение нашли?

Comment: Когда выкладывал, не заметил ваш комментарий. Синхронно, видимо) Спасибо за уделенное время!